# Angular switch from lazyLoading to 'normal' loading

Tags: angular, angular-module

I am working on an Angular application that has lazy loading implemented. I tried experimenting with lazy loading but decided that I do not yet want to implement it in my application. This is my `app.module.ts`:

**app.module.ts**:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'store', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'hq', loadChildren: 'app/hq/hq.module#HqModule' },
      { path: 'store', loadChildren: 'app/store/store.module#StoreModule', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
    ]),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I switch my route to for example `hq` back to normal loading? I expected that something as follows would work:

```js
{ path: 'hq', redirectTo: HqModule }
```

That however returns that my module is a wrong type of argument. Is this even possible in Angular?

**hq.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: '',
          component: HqTemplateComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
          children: [
            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'overview' },
            { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
          ]
        },
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [HqTemplateComponent, OverviewComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Arrow function

I like doing it by changing string to arrow function looking something like:

```typescript
import { HqModule } from './hq/hq.module';


{ path: 'hq', loadChildren: () => HqModule },
```

for **aot angular 4 and less**:

```typescript
export function loadHqModuleFn() {
  return HqModule;
}

{ path: 'hq', loadChildren: loadHqModuleFn },
```

**Note:** *Beginning in version 5, the compiler automatically performs this rewritting while emitting the .js file. Thanks to "expression lowering"*

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SHVOPdAXJq0uf7Qz3Wne?p=preview)**

### angular-router-loader?sync=true

If you use [angular-router-loader](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader) then you should be aware that this loaded has special syntax for [to load module synchronously](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader#synchronous-loading). Just add the `sync=true` as a query string value to your `loadChildren string`:

```typescript
{ path: 'hq', loadChildren: 'app/hq/hq.module#HqModule?sync=true' },
```

### imports

Of course you can just add module to `imports` array but in this case you have to change router config path for this module:

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,       
    HqModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'store', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'store', loadChildren: 'app/store/store.module#StoreModule', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
    ])
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**hq.module.ts**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: 'hq', <========================== changed '' to `hq`
          component: HqTemplateComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
          children: [
            ...
          ]
        },
    ]),
  ],
  ...
})
```

It's also worth mentioning that angular router config is strict about order. According to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration):

> The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so
>   more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes

So add modules with routes definition to `imports` array in the same order as if you would do it in `RouterModule.forRoot`.

Comment: I am trying to get your arrow working solution up and running, it doesn't work for my angular-cli instance:

ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 27:38 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in /project/project-frontend/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Add `HqModule` to your AppModule's import array and remove HqModule entry from the AppModule routing definition. Like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HqModule, // add it
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'store', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'store', loadChildren: 'app/store/store.module#StoreModule', pathMatch: 'prefix'}
    ])
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppModule { }
```