# Proper route configuration for eager loading Grand Child Components Angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have three nested modules in my app. **app.module -> leaves.module -> balance.module** I wan't to eager load the leaves module and balance module. The app works as expected when I have the router configuration for **both leaves.module and balance.module** in **leaves.routing.module**. But I want the route configuration for the **balance.module** in the **balance.routing.module**.

**app.module**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, Page404Component, DashboardComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, LeavesModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.routing.module**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", component: Page404Component }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**leaves.module**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LeavesComponent,
    ApplyComponent,
    Page404leavesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BalanceModule,
    LeavesRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class LeavesModule { }
```

**leaves.routing.module**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "leaves",
    component: LeavesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "apply",
        component: ApplyComponent
      },
      //******HOW TO MOVE CHILD ROUTE CONFIG TO CHILD MODULE ?********* */
      {
        path: "balance",
        component: BalanceComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: "casual",
            component: CasualComponent
          },
          {
            path: "earned",
            component: EarnedComponent
          },
          {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "casual",
            pathMatch: "full"
          },
          { path: "**", component: Page404balanceComponent }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "apply",
        pathMatch: "full"
      },
      { path: "**", component: Page404leavesComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LeavesRoutingModule {}
```

**balance.module**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BalanceComponent,
    CasualComponent,
    EarnedComponent,
    Page404balanceComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BalanceRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class BalanceModule { }
```

**balance.routing.module**

```js
const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BalanceRoutingModule {}
```

When I move the router config of **balance.module** in to **balance.routing.module** like follows, the **balance.module** doesn't render at all and **page404leaves** is shown.

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
        path: "balance",
        component: BalanceComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: "casual",
            component: CasualComponent
          },
          {
            path: "earned",
            component: EarnedComponent
          },
          {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "casual",
            pathMatch: "full"
          },
          { path: "**", component: Page404balanceComponent }
        ]
      }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BalanceRoutingModule {}
```

What is the right way to do this? I think in a design perspective, child modules should hold its own routes.

[See code on Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routing-with-modules-with-bootstrap-6anhxy?file=src/app/leaves/leaves-routing.module.ts)

Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of separating the child modules if you are not going to lazy load them?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Thanks for the response. The grand child component in the grand child module is the first page of my app. So I believe that module should be eager loaded. As per separation of concerns, I would like to have the child route configuration inside the child module itself. (if Angular allows that)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626594/angular-switch-from-lazyloading-to-normal-loading